# How to access an array of JavaBeans from a session

Tags: java, jsp, session, jdbc, javabeans

I am currently trying to display the a list of user donations (it's for a project) in the donations panel page but would it be possible to pass an array of JavaBeans to a session bean. What I have in mind is

```
private UserDonationBean []u = new UserDonationBean();
```

and I'll initialize bean attributes according to the corresponding database information then put u to the session object via setAttribute(). Would this method be possible? How am I going to access each bean in my JSP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it sounds ok. Just like you said.
Access from JSP depends on what technologies you using inside. 
The vanilla way would be through the 'session' variable that's always available in JSP unless you explicitly disabled it:

```
   <%  UserDonationBean[] u = (UserDonationBean[]) session.getAttribute("YOUR_KEY") 
   %>
```

If you use EL then its

```
${sessionScope["YOUR_KEY"] }
```

Just some minor points to consider:
(1) Obviously if you only need it for the page, you can also put it on request scope

(2) In some **production** environment you might want UserDonationBean to be Serializable (UserDonationBean implements Serializable), because the container might want to send it across a cluster, or save it to disc.

Comment: Eclipse says it cannot be resolved to a type. Did I miss something out here?

Comment: At the top of your jsp, do you have a page import? e..g <%@ page import="mypackage.UserDonationBean" %>

Comment: Oh. I thought I was gonna use it with usebean. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
private UserDonationBean []u = new UserDonationBean();
HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
session.setAttribute("beanArray", UserDonationBean);
u = (UserDonationBean[])session.getAttribute("beanArray");
```